# How to arrange clickable links in a circle using HTML?

Tags: html

May I know how to arrange the clickable links of a website into a circle? I imagined the website to be like this.

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVWh1.jpg)

Those words in white are the clickable links. How do we pull it off to reproduce the result?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chained CSS transforms like in [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/placing-items-circle/) example.

It then works this way:

```css
 @for $i from 1 through $item-count {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        transform: 
          rotate($rot * 1deg) 
          translate($circle-size / 2) 
          rotate($rot * -1deg);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to do this.

```
element {
     position:absolute;
     top:100px;
     left:100px;
}
```

`top` is your y value, and `left` is your x value

Answer (score 0):

I think I knew how after seeing the answers from our intrepid comrades. Although I have 65% satisfaction of those answers, it will serve me well.

The HTML code to arrange the clickable links in a circle is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.container {
  --d: 6.5em; /* image size */
  --rel: 1; /* how much extra space we want between images, 1 = one image size */
  --r: calc(.5*(1 + var(--rel))*var(--d)/var(--tan)); /* circle radius */
  --s: calc(2*var(--r) + var(--d)); /* container size */
  position: relative;
  width: var(--s); height: var(--s);
  background: silver /* to show images perfectly fit in container */
}

.container a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  margin: calc(-.5*var(--d));
  width: var(--d); height: var(--d);
  --az: calc(var(--i)*1turn/var(--m));
  transform: 
    rotate(var(--az)) 
    translate(var(--r))
    rotate(calc(-1*var(--az)))
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container" style="--m: 8; --tan: 0.41">
  <a style="--i: 1"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    Wacky Ideas
  </a>
  <a style="--i: 2"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    Galleries
  </a>
  <a style="--i: 3"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    Blogs
  </a>
  <a style="--i: 4"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    The Future
  </a>
  <a style="--i: 5"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    My Adventures
  </a>
  <a style="--i: 6"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    Homepage
  </a>
  <a style="--i: 7"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    Know Thomas
  </a>
  <a style="--i: 8"; href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    Play with Thomas
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Giving you the output like this:

[Clickable links arranged in a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQe5j.png)